# how to show my tableview in my popoverController with data

Tags: ios

Now I have created a popoverController with a tableview in it and also, I created the data that will be shown in the tableview. However, the table is always empty.
P.S.(the delegate and datasource have been set and the delegate methods have been called,too)

the method that create the data in the tableview:

```
-(void) createCategoryData
{
NSMutableArray *categoriesForJiangSu;
NSMutableArray *categoriesForZheJiang;

categorySections=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"JiangSu",@"ZheJiang", nil];
categoriesForJiangSu=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
categoriesForZheJiang=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[categoriesForJiangSu addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"package 1",@"name",
                                 @"JiangSu.jpg",@"picture",nil]];
[categoriesForJiangSu addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"package 2",@"name",
                                 @"JiangSu.jpg",@"picture",nil]];
[categoriesForZheJiang addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"package 1",@"name",
                                  @"ZheJiang.jpg",@"picture",nil]];
[categoriesForZheJiang addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"package 2",@"name",
                                  @"ZheJiang.jpg",@"picture",nil]];

categoryData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:categoriesForJiangSu,categoriesForZheJiang, nil];
[categoriesForJiangSu release];
[categoriesForZheJiang release];


}
```

here are the delegate methods:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSections
{
return [categorySections count];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [[categoryData objectAtIndex:section] count];
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:     (NSInteger)section
{
return [categorySections objectAtIndex:section];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[tableView
                                           dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell==nil)
{
    cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc]
           initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
           reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
[[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[[[categoryData
                                                  objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                                objectForKey:@"picture"]]];

[[cell textLabel] setText:[[[categoryData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]
                            objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]];
cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
return cell;
}
```

The viewDidLoad method for popoverController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[self createCategoryData];
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover=CGSizeMake(200.0, 320.0);
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

And the showPopover method in the mainViewController:

```
-(IBAction)showPopover:(id)sender
{
if(popoverController==nil)
{
    popoverController=[[UIPopoverController alloc]
                       initWithContentViewController:popoverContentViewController];
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    popoverController.delegate=self;
}
}
```

the popoverContentViewController is the name of popoverController.

Comment: You need to give us some details about what you've tried. I'm assuming you are doing this in code? Show us some of your code...it is very difficult to try to help you with the little you gave.

Comment: It looks to me as though you never added your table as a subview.

Comment: @CodaFi I'm a beginner to ios, so could you please tell me how to add the table as a subview?

Comment: `[self.view addSubview:self.nameOfMyTable];`

Comment: @CodaFi No, it doesn't work... actually in the popoverController.xib file I drag in a tableView, so I'm not sure if it's necessary to add my table as a subview.

Comment: No, it isn't then... I just noticed, do you really have an array inside an array inside an array inside a dictionary?  That's insane!  Break that up and make your life simpler.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint inside, say cellForRowAtIndexPath, does it stop there? I'm curious if the delegates are even being called. Furthermore, what have you set the table's delegate to?

Comment: @CodaFi No, I don't think so.. categoryData stores specific information that'll show in the table. Since there're two sections,JiangSu & ZheJiang, i created two arrays correspond to them,categoriesForJiangSu & categoriesForZheJiang. Each array has several dictionaries. One dictionary stores details of one record.

Comment: @KerriShotts i did what the textbooks say, to set the table's delegate to popoverController.

Comment: @CodaFi the logic relationship is correct, i guess..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a beginner dont use xib if u r not clear about xib concepts..Better get your work done without xib,as CodaFi suggested .add your table view to controllers view that u r passing to popoverController.

Comment: I did what you told me to do, i got my work done without xib, however it didn't work either..

Comment: it's really driving me crazy now, i have no idea where the problem is